# Identify whether remote machine connection disconnected or not ( RDP or RDCMan)

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a set of remote machines where I need to connect always. Since there is no autoconnect available for RDCMan/RDP on disconnection, we are planning to check whether a remote machine got disconnected or not. So that we can connect the same.

Is there a way to get log file? or how I can determine whether a remote machine got disconnected or not, by script.

How I can automate the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> netstat -an | select-string ":3389" | select-string "ESTABLISHED"

using this command i can get the list of RDC host connected, and by comparing a list of server with the output, I can query the disconnected server name.